# Python installation on CentoOS 7 - problem with the zlib version

Tags: python-3.x, zlib

I tried an online editor for python3: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php

and executed below lines:

```
import zlib
print (zlib.ZLIB_VERSION)

[Output: 1.2.11]
```

And then I installed python3 using these instructions: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-on-centos-7/

However, I get "1.2.7" in my output for the above zlib version check.

Is there a way to get zlib version with 1.2.11 with the python installation on CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue, I ended up building and installing Python 3.6.3 myself along with Zlib version 1.2.11.

After downloading python folder, I modified Python3.6.3/Modules/Setup file to include the desired version of Zlib version.

Here is the line that was modified:

```
#zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz
// Uncomment this line and provide path to Zlib1.2.11 for both include and lib folders.
```

Then just make -> make install for Python and you should all set. There are plenty of instructions to install Python so I would avoid too much details on that.